# How can I reference a Dockerfile relative to the ansible role task YAML file?

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile

I have an Ansible repo with the following directory path

```
.
├── kube-init.sh
├── provisioning
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── all.yml
│   ├── roles
│   │   └── app_deploy
│   │       ├── files
│   │       │   ├── secretfile
│   │       ├── tasks
│   │       │   ├── docker
│   │       │   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │       │   └── main.yml
│   │       └── vars
│   │           └── main.yaml
│   └── site.yml
├── README.md
```

I'm trying to define a docker build image task at `provisioning/roles/app_deploy/tasks/main.yaml` as follows

```yaml
- name: Build image and with build args
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  docker_image:
    name: app-name
    build:
      path: docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        log_volume: /var/log/svm
        listen_port: 8080
    state: present
    source: build
```

I can't quite get the Dockerfile/context to be made available to the ansible task. Played around with various combinations of relative/absolute values of `path` and `dockerfile` combinations.

I thought the most obvious choice would be to skip using `dockerfile` and just use `path` as `./docker` which didn't work to my surprise.

Using Ansible with Python3 with Docker SDK above v5

A bit more context. I'm actually using Vagrant with Openstack plugin to provision the new compute with my Ansible tasks. The plugin copies the contents of the repo (Ansible) on to the target machine at the path `/home/vagrant`, and runs the provisioning scripts from there.

Comment: Have you copied the said _Dockerfile_ on the target node prior to your trial to build it?

Comment: Please show an [mcve](/help/mcve) with an inventory, a complete playbook, an execution example... As is we don't know on which target you are executing this task on, if you copied the Dockerfile there prior to building or not, what is the exact error you are getting...

Comment: Moreover, although not an error in itself, having a `Dockerfile` inside a role's `tasks` sub-directory looks like a very bad idea. At the very least, it should go inside the `files` sub-directory. And IMO, as a general case, it should not even be inside your Ansible project tree but in a separate git repository with all the rest of the build context that you clone prior to building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the right path to pass for the docker module the following way. I added a debug task below to figure out the current working directory on which my `app_deploy/tasks/main.yml` runs from as

```yaml
- name: Find out playbook's path
  shell: pwd
  register: playbook_path_output
- debug: var=playbook_path_output.stdout
```

which was returning me `provisioning/roles`. I realized that the path to be from where `site.yml` was located which defines one of the roles to be `app_deploy`.

So with that, I modified the docker module path as

```yaml
- name: Build image and with build args
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  docker_image:
    name: app-name
    build:
      path: ./roles/app_deploy/tasks/docker/
      args:
        log_volume: /var/log/svm
        listen_port: 8080
    state: present
    source: build
```

---

But per  [Zeitounator's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003886/how-can-i-reference-a-dockerfile-relative-to-the-task-yaml-file/72011398#comment127239339_72003886), the above might not be a right practice to store the Dockerfile and its constituent files inside a particular role directory.